# Unable to save files owned by root WSL2 VSCODE

Tags: visual-studio-code, wsl-2

I have a project that the files are owned by root, for example:

```
> ls -la
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     36 May  6 20:57 README
```

and the project is inside a WSL2 and I am using VSCODE.
When I am trying to save a change I get the following error message:

```
Failed to save 'README': Unable to write file 'vscode-remote://wsl+centos7/home/foteas/code/AppSrc/README' (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/foteas/code/AppSrc/README')
```

I do not want to change the ownership of the files or the folders.
Is there any way to edit the file as root via the VSCODE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue. There are a few workarounds proposed in the github issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/48659#issuecomment-830849282).

From Xunnamius on github:

> Rather than enter a security nightmare with root ssh logins and running code as root, I created `acl-enable-for` and `acl-disable-for` simple little scripts taken from the solutions above.
>
> For example, I run `acl-enable-for /etc/nginx` and make a note to run `acl-disable-for /etc/nginx` later. Note that `acl-disable-for` deletes *all* ACLs on a path recursively.
>
> > You may have to replace $USER with your literal username in the command below
>
> `/usr/local/bin/acl-enable-for`:
>
> ```sh
> #!/usr/bin/env bash
>
> # * Enables a read/write ACL on the chosen path(s) recursively
>
> set -e
> # ? Ensure we're running as root
> if [[ `id -u` -ne 0 ]]; then
>     echo 'acl-enable-for: please run as root!'
>     exit 1
> fi
> set +e
> setfacl -R -m u:$USER:rwx "$@"
> # setfacl -R -m u:$USER:rw "$@" # a bit more restrictive
> ```
>
> `/usr/local/bin/acl-disable-for`:
>
> ```sh
> #!/usr/bin/env bash
>
> # * Clears all ACLs on a chosen path recursively
>
> set -e
> # ? Ensure we're running as root
> if [[ `id -u` -ne 0 ]]; then
>     echo 'acl-disable-for: please run as root!'
>     exit 1
> fi
> set +e
> setfacl -Rb "$@"
> ```